# How to get the last child node inside matching selector in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
const slidesLength = slideRight.querySelectorAll('div').length / 2;

<div class="right-slide">
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic1.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic2.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic3.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic4.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic5.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to target the inner most  using querySelectorAll(), but I am unsure of how to do that. With the JS code I have right now, I am able to to get the exact number of divs I want, but only by using a different method. I was wondering whether or not there is a way where I can disregard the divs with background-color and only obtain the ones with background image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `document.querySelectorAll('.right-slide div[style*=background-image]')` will get a list together of all divs inside of `.right-slide` that have a `background-image` as an inline style

```js
const bgImageDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.right-slide div[style*=background-image]');
console.log(bgImageDivs)
```

```html
<div class="right-slide">
  <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
    <div style="background-image: url(/pic1.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
    <div style="background-image: url(/pic2.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
    <div style="background-image: url(/pic3.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
    <div style="background-image: url(/pic4.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
    <div style="background-image: url(/pic5.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you know that the divs you want will always be the most deeply nested ones, you can just use `document.querySelector('.div.right-slide > div > div')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop to check it if the `div` has `background-image` or not.

```js
let div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
let num =0;
for(let i =0;i<div.length;i++){
if(div[i].style.backgroundImage !=='')
num++
}
console.log(num)
```

```html
<div class="right-slide">

            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic1.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic2.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic3.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic4.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #773f47bd">
                <div style="background-image: url(/pic5.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```